# Admob - How to pause interstitial ad

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

Is there any way to pause/resume an Admob interstitial ad on Android?
I give rewards for watching video ads and I want a dialog box to pop up when the user clicks the back button (the ad should pause first). E.g. Do you wish to forfeit the reward? Yes/No

Also I would like the ad to pause if the app is put in the background and then resume when the app is brought back to the front.

I can't find anything on the Admob website and other questions on this site have not solved the problem eg [How to pause interstitial Ads when Android application goes to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990793/how-to-pause-interstitial-ads-when-android-application-goes-to-background)

I imagine I need to put something here:

```
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {          

        }           

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

        }

    });
```

And likely in here too:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {   

}
```

I have seen ads pause in other apps so I know it's possible. Is there a simple pause method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [RewardedVideoAd](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video) by AdMob for your requirement. If you're using AdMob with Firebase, you can easily integrate Reward video Ad in your App.

RewardVideoAd having `resume()`, `pause()` and `destroy()` method, call it in your Activity's `onResume()`, `onPause()` and in `onDestroy()` method respectively.